# What is $\pi(u)$ where $\pi: V \to V/U$

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

If $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space and $U$ a subspace of $V$. Defining $\pi: V \to V/U$, where for $v \in V$, $\pi(v) = v+U$. I would please like to verify what $\pi(u)$ is for $u\in U$.

I would like to say it is the $0$ element in $V/U$. But how do I complete the RHS?

Is it $\pi(u)= u+U=0+U=U$? or $=0$?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\;U\;$ is a *subspace* of $\;V\;$ , then $\;\pi u=u+U=U=\overline 0\;$ , with $\;\overline0=\;$ the zero element (vector) of the quotient space $\;V/U\;$ . Of course, within the context of the quotient space, $\;U\;$ is always the zero vector, no need to denote it $\;\overline0\;$ if this is clear.

Comment: Now have to wait 9 min to accept

Comment: @TheBirdistheWord Thanks. Don't worry.